# Can you Get-ADUser -Filter -Not MemberOf to look for 2 groups?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have the below code that looks for users that are not a member of a group.  I would like to filter to not a member of group A as well as not a member of group B

```
    # Set the name of the specific group that should trigger copying
    $groupA = "GroupA"
    $copyDN = (Get-ADGroup $groupA).DistinguishedName
    
    # Set the name of the VPN users group that should trigger copying
    $groupB = "GroupB"
    $vpnDN = (Get-ADGroup $GroupB).DistinguishedName

    $targetOU = "OU=Users,OU=Lab01,DC=dbss,DC=tech"
    
    $usersToProcess = Get-ADUser -Filter ("-not memberof -RecursiveMatch '$groupA'") -SearchBase $targetOU -SearchScope OneLevel -Properties DisplayName,SamAccountName,Mobile,Pager
```

Is there a better way to use Get-ADUser to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea how to do it with the `-Filter` syntax but with LDAP Syntax (`-LDAPFilter`) this is how your query would look like:

```
# Set the name of the specific group that should trigger copying
$groupA = 'GroupA'
$copyDN = (Get-ADGroup $groupA).DistinguishedName

# Set the name of the VPN users group that should trigger copying
$groupB = 'GroupB'
$vpnDN = (Get-ADGroup $GroupB).DistinguishedName

$getADUserSplat = @{
    # Not a memberof `$copyDN` AND Not a memberof `$vpnDN`
    LDAPFilter  = '(&(!memberof={0})(!memberof={1}))' -f $copyDN, $vpnDN
    SearchBase  = 'OU=Users,OU=Lab01,DC=dbss,DC=tech'
    SearchScope = 'OneLevel'
    Properties  = 'DisplayName', 'SamAccountName', 'Mobile', 'Pager'
}

$usersToProcess = Get-ADUser @getADUserSplat
```

If you wanted to do a recursive lookup for any of those groups you would need to include [**LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN**](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) to your filter:

```
LDAPFilter = '(&(!memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={0})(!memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={1}))' -f $copyDN, $vpnDN
```